# gulp generates TypeError: The Streams property must be of type function

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, pipeline, gulp-uglify

I got an error `TypeError: The "streams[stream.length - 1]" property must be of type function. Received an instance of Pumpify` while trying to minify a javascript using **gulp** package ,

```
Using gulpfile MY_PROJECT_PATH\gulpfile.js
Starting 'compress'...
'compress' errored after 21 ms
TypeError: The "streams[stream.length - 1]" property must be of type function. Received an instance of Pumpify
at popCallback (MY_PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\internal\streams\pipeline.js:59:3)
at pipeline (MY_PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\internal\streams\pipeline.js:134:37
```

This is my code in [gulpfile.js]

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var pipeline = require('readable-stream').pipeline;

gulp.task('compress', function () {
   return pipeline(
       gulp.src('DIR_NAME/*.js'),
       uglify(),
       gulp.dest('DIR_NAME/dist')
   );
});
```

The package.json file: I tried to install [pipeline, readable-stream, pumpify] while debugging

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
     "gulp": "^4.0.2",
     "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.2",
     "pipeline": "^0.1.3",
     "pumpify": "^2.0.1",
     "readable-stream": "^4.3.0"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Solution 1

The [`pipeline`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#streampipelinesource-transforms-destination-callback) function from `stream` or `readable_stream` expects a callback as a last parameter.

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var pipeline = require('readable-stream').pipeline;

gulp.task('compress', function (cb) {
    return pipeline(
        gulp.src('DIR_NAME/*.js'),
        uglify(),
        gulp.dest('DIR_NAME/dist'),
        cb
    );
});
```

### Solution 2

`stream/promises` exposes a promise-based version of [`pipeline`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#streampipelinesource-transforms-destination-options) which does not use a callback:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var pipeline = require('stream/promises').pipeline;

gulp.task('compress', async function () {
    await pipeline(
        gulp.src('DIR_NAME/*.js'),
        uglify(),
        gulp.dest('DIR_NAME/dist')
    );
});
```

### Solution 3

Then there is the tradition way of piping steams, with the [`.pipe()`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#readablepipedestination-options) method.

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('compress', function () {
    return gulp.src('DIR_NAME/*.js')
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('DIR_NAME/dist'));
});
```